# How to inject method result of a service as an argument for another service?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a `FooService` that's fetches some data from another config service.

I have that config service as the config is different depending on the request data. The config service has the `RequestStack` injected and builds the relevant config array.

My `FooService` looks as follows:

```
class Foo
{
    private $config;

    /**
     * @param Config $config
     */
    public function __construct(Config $config) {
        $this->config = $config->getData();
    }
}
```

Yet instead of injecting the service, I prefer to inject only the method call result of `getData`, as it is simpler for unit testing. I won't need to mock the config, I can just pass an array.

My current `service.yml` has a definition like:

```
config:
    ...

foo:
    class: Kopernikus\LeBundle\Service\Foo
    arguments:
        - @config
```

I tried changing my `foo` definition like for factory methods via:

```
foo:
    class: Kopernikus\LeBundle\Service\Foo
    arguments:
        - [@config, getData]
```

yet this too injects the whole service.

How to inject method result of a service as an argument for another service?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this with the expression language ([New in Symfony 2.4](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-expressionlanguage-component))

As described in the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#using-the-expression-language) you can do something as example:

```
config:
    ...

foo:
    class: Kopernikus\LeBundle\Service\Foo
        arguments:    ["@=service('config').getData()"]
```

Hope this help

Comment: The brackets are too much here, as they inject an array of an array. Just `"@=service('config').getData()"` suffices. =)

Comment: It has been moved [here](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/service_container/expression_language.html) since version **3**

Answer (score -1):

You're basically asking for a dependency injection container. You can make your own that has a simple function (such as) `get()` that returns a new instance of `Foo`? You can define it to create new objects upon each invocation of `get()`, or more of a singleton that always returns the same object (by storing it in a private static variable).

eg,

```
<?php
class FooContainer implements YourContainerInterface {
    public static function get() {
        // Config logic here
        return new Foo($config);
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like OP is asking for how to inject the result of a method call to a service instead of the service itself -- although I don't clearly understand why they would want to do that so I may be misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @JeremyHarris I have updated the use case for why I want to do this.

Comment: The only way to pass a function in such a way is via string, which really isn't ideal since you can't do any type checking on it (without using additional logic). The appropriate way to do it in PHP is via container object.

Comment: I don't see the upsides of this esp. comparing to the other two provided answers. I also don't get why type checking wouldn't be possible otherwise. The config function currently returns an array an in the constructor of the dependent service I can use that typehint (or if I ever change to an object use its class typehint). Could you please elaborate when this approach would have benefits? Or what benefits I am not seeing comparing to the other answers?

Comment: If you have a class that expects a DI container, so that it can access a service, you can type-hint according to that specific DI container, or it's parent class/interface. The other examples use various forms of PHP magic by using strings as parameters, then parsing the strings, and returning an object. This is wasteful and slow. Passing a DI container object that returns a service is significantly more performant.